# Accessing child class variables through parent class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, smart-pointers

I am making a simple 2D physics engine for circles and squares. I have a body class that I want to be given a unique_ptr instance of a shape when created. The shape can either be a circle or a box. The body is the object that I want to throw into my game loop to check for collisions. When checking for collisions, I am interested in the data associated with the shapes. A very primitive example is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Shape
{
    virtual float calculateArea() const = 0;
};

struct Circle: public Shape
{
    const float m_radius;
    Circle(float radius) : m_radius(radius) {} 
    float calculateArea() const {return m_radius*m_radius*3.14;}
};

struct Square: public Shape
{
    const float m_side_length;
    Square(float side_length) : m_side_length(side_length) {}
    float calculateArea() const {return m_side_length*m_side_length;}
};

struct Body
{
    Body(std::unique_ptr<Shape>& shape): m_shape(std::move(shape)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> m_shape;
};



int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> circ = std::make_unique<Circle>(5.0);
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> square = std::make_unique<Square>(10.0);
    std::shared_ptr<Body> body1 = std::make_shared<Body>(circ);
    std::shared_ptr<Body> body2 = std::make_shared<Body>(square);
}
```

Essentially, I am wondering if there is a way to access the radius of a shape or the side length of a shape. I can see that something like

`body1->shape->m_radius` or `body2->shape->m_side_length` doesn't work but I really want to find a solution where my shapes can be grouped into a general shape class and I'm still able to access their unique features through the body class. This is for collision detection btw.

I saw some related posts such as here: [Access members of derived class through base class pointer C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265280/access-members-of-derived-class-through-base-class-pointer-c) but the overall problem is slightly different from mine and the question is quite old.

Thanks for the help - hope it makes sense!

Comment: Read up a bit more on `virtual` functions. A base class knows nothing about any derived classes, and cannot as a new derived class can be added years after the base class was last compiled. But if it contains `virtual` functions, the derived classes can override those functions and take more specific actions, operating on its member variables and perhaps returning them.

Comment: Yeah I have a virtual function in the example here - the only issue is that the derived classes may have different quantities of data. I'm sure I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: In most cases you expand the interface of the base class with virtual function to handle all the cases where specific knowledge is required without the user needing to have any of that specific knowledge. When you have cases where you cannot do this, inheritance is probably not the right solution. See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/4581301) for a tool to help determine when inheritance is a bad idea even when it might look like a good idea on the surface.

Comment: In this specific case, it makes no sense for a `shape` to have a radius because most shape-derived classes will not have a radius. If you need to get this information from a shape, inheritance is not the right tool, at least not at `shape` level. Also see the example of the rectangle vs the square in the Liskov link given above.

Comment: It works the other way around, child classes can know things of their parent classes not the other way around. Also using inheritance for drawing shapes it not all that nice either.  Watch this : [Breaking dependencies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn6OqefuH08)  from cppcon. It shows stuff about drawing.  TLDR whatever you think inheritance usually isn't the solution

Comment: Another good trick is the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Instead of getting stuff *out* of the derived class to do a calculation or overriding a `virtual` function to perform the operation inside the derived class, you pass an object into the derived class that the derived class uses to perform a job that it otherwise doesn't know how to do. You don't even need formal inheritance at all.

Comment: @user4581301 Seems like inheritance maybe isn't the solution here then - it makes sense to look into different design patterns. Sounds like I could make the visitor pattern work with shapes. The type-erased example from that youtube video is a little out of my pay-grade as I'm relatively new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I am wondering if there is a way to access the radius of a shape or the side length of a shape.

Yes, there are ways of getting derived class members but I don't recommend taking that route to solve your programming problem. It can get hairy pretty quickly.

Let's say there are N sub-classes of `shape`. Given two `shape` objects, if collision detection logic depends on the object types, you will need <sup>N</sup>C<sub>2</sub> functions to cover the functionality.

One way to do this would be to have a registry of collision detection logic classes/functions. You can add entries to the registry when your program starts. You will need to add code to look up the registry for a class/function for two object types, and then call the functions. In the class/function that implements the detection logic, it's fair to use `dynamic_cast` to get the specific object types and get the necessary data from the specific object types.

Here's an outline of what that entails.

```
class CollisionDetector
{
    public:
        virtual bool detectCollision(
            shape const& shape1,
            shape const& shape2) const;
};

class CollisionDetectorRegistry
{
    public:
        using CollisionDectorBuilder = CollisionDetector*(void);

        static void registerCollisionDetector(
            std::string const& shapeType1,
            std::string const& shapeType2,
            CollisionDectorBuilder builder);

        static CollisionDetector* getCollisionDetector(
            shape const& shape1,
            shape const& shape2);
};

class CircleCircleCollisionDetector : public CollisionDetector
{
    public:

        // It is fair to dynamic_cast shape1 and shape2 to circle
        // In the function.
        virtual bool detectCollision(
            shape const& shape1,
            shape const& shape2) const;

        static CollisionDetector* build();
}

class CircleSquareCollisionDetector : public CollisionDetector
{
    public:

        // It is fair to dynamic_cast shape1 and shape2 to circle/square
        // In the function.
        virtual bool detectCollision(
            shape const& shape1,
            shape const& shape2) const;

        static CollisionDetector* build();
}

// Add the following in some place that is executed at start up time.

CollisionDetectorRegistry::registerCollisionDetector(
   "circle", "circle", CircleCircleCollisionDetector::build);

CollisionDetectorRegistry::registerCollisionDetector(
   "circle", "square", CircleSquareCollisionDetector::build);

// Shape-independent function for detecting collision
bool detectCollision(
    shape const& shape1,
    shape const& shape2)
{
    CollisionDetector* detector = 
        CollisionDetectorRegistry::getCollisionDetector(shape1, shape2);
    if ( detector == nullptr )
    {
       // Throw an execption.
    }
    else
    {
        return detector->detectCollision(shape1, shape2);
    }
}
```

I realize that you'll need to fill some gaps but I am assuming you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. You mentioned that this method can "get very hairy quicky". Could you lay out an approach where this can be minimized? I will definitely using your example as guidance.

Comment: @bboan *Could you lay out an approach where this can be minimized?* I thought I did that in my answer.